# map() function with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

There is quite some topics posted about how async/await behaves in javascript map function, but still, detail explanation in bellow two examples would be nice:

```
  const resultsPromises = myArray.map(async number => {
    return await getResult(number);
  });
```

```
  const resultsPromises = myArray.map(number => {
    return getResult(number);
  });
```

*edited: this if of course a fictional case, so just opened for debate, why,how and when should map function wait for await keyword. solutions how to modify this example, calling Promise.all() is kind of not the aim of this question.

`getResult` is an async function*

Comment: Combine this with a `Promise.all`.

Comment: Sure, on the first example await is returning the resolved promise result, means the real data of your getResult. 
The second example is returning a promise, you will need to resolve each promise with.then()

Comment: @Alnitak I agree it is a smell, but I have used it when I need to deal with service throttling or purposeful, sequential, async.

Comment: @arielb - not true - an `async` function _always_ returns a `Promise`, so all that's happening is that it's waiting for `getResult()` to be resolved, and then passing that as the value of a _new_ `Promise`.

Comment: @Alnitak you are right, I was misunderstood.

Comment: I would simply write `const resultPromises = indicators.map(getResult)`, no need for async/await, your function is already returning a Promise and you don't need to await anything

Comment: @TylerRoper I believe you are wrong.  `.map` will not wait for the internal `await` to complete, so the effect is that they will all run in parallel.

Comment: @ZacDelventhal it would, if the `async` callback containing an `await` actually made any sense at all (which it doesn't)

Comment: Well this if of course a fictional case, so just opened for debate, why should map function wait for `await` keyword.
solutions how to modify this example, calling `Promise.all()` is kind of not the aim of this question.

Comment: @marko424 that's simple - _it doesn't_.

Comment: Also the same (using the implicit return for brevity): `const resultsPromises = indicators.map(async indicator => getResult(indicator));`

Comment: @Alnitak can you provide codepen?

Comment: @Wex, why would you put async there ? you are not using await inside it

Comment: The linter that I use (tslint:[promise-function-async](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/promise-function-async/)) enforces that functions that return promises must be async, so I've become accustomed to the style.

Comment: @marko424 you _can't_ make `.map` wait for all of the promises.  You either use `Promise.all`, or you use a different function instead of `.map` that _does_ know how to wait for them.

Comment: Alnitak, thanks but not really answering my question.

Comment: @marko424 your actual question is unclear (unless you edit it) because the two code examples you've provided don't actually have the different behaviour you expected them to.

Comment: @Alnizak thanks that's the answer that I want to hear :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The other answers have pretty well covered the details of how your examples behave, but I wanted to *try* to state it more succinctly.

```js
const resultsPromises = myArray.map(async number => {
  return await getResult(number);
});
```

```js
const resultsPromises = myArray.map(number => {
  return getResult(number);
});
```

1. `Array.prototype.map` synchronously loops through an array and transforms each element to the return value of its callback.
2. Both examples *return a `Promise`*.

   - `async` functions **always** return a `Promise`.
   - `getResult` returns a `Promise`.
   - Therefore, if there are no errors you can think of them both in pseudocode as:

```js
const resultsPromises = myArray.map(/* map each element to a Promise */);
```

3. As [zero298 stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225769/8550747) and [alnitak demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225837/8550747), this very quickly (synchronously) starts off each promise in order; however, since they're run in parallel each promise will resolve/reject as they see fit and will likely not settle (fulfill or reject) in order.
4. Either run the promises in parallel and collect the results with `Promise.all` or run them sequentially using a [for * loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225769/8550747) or [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225745/8550747).

Alternatively, you could use a third-party module for [chainable asynchronous JavaScript methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af) I maintain to clean things up and--perhaps--make the code match your intuition of how an [async map](https://async-af.js.org/AsyncAF#mapAF) operation might work:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const getResult = async n => {
  await delay(Math.random() * 1000);
  console.log(n);
  return n;
};

(async () => {
  console.log('parallel:');
  await AsyncAF([1, 2, 3]).map(getResult).then(console.log);
  
  console.log('sequential:');
  await AsyncAF([1, 2, 3]).series.map(getResult).then(console.log)
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/async-af@7.0.12/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: `return await` in an async call is useless and inefficient as async functions will return a promise either way

Answer (score 13):

`async/await` is usefull when you want to flatten your code by removing the `.then()` callbacks or if you want to implicitly return a Promise:

```js
const delay = n => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n));

async function test1() {
  await delay(200);
  // do something usefull here
  console.log('hello 1');
}

async function test2() {
  return 'hello 2'; // this returned value will be wrapped in a Promise
}

test1();
test2().then(console.log);
```

However, in your case, you are not using `await` to replace a `.then()`, nor are you using it to return an implicit Promise since your function already returns a Promise. So they are not necessary.

## Parallel execution of all the Promises

If you want to run all Promises in parallel, I would suggest to simply return the result of `getResult` with `map()` and generate an array of Promises. The Promises will be started sequentially but will eventually run in parallel.

```
const resultsPromises = indicators.map(getResult);
```

Then you can await all promises and get the resolved results using `Promise.all()`:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3];

const getResult = x => new Promise(res => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(x);
    res(x);
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
});

Promise.all(data.map(getResult)).then(console.log);
```

## Sequential execution of the Promises

However, if you want to run each Promise sequentially and wait for the previous Promise to resolve before running the next one, then you can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and `async/await` like this:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3];

const getResult = x => new Promise(res => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(x);
    res(x);
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
});

data.reduce(async (previous, x) => {
  const result = await previous;
  return [...result, await getResult(x)];
}, Promise.resolve([])).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 8):

`Array.prototype.map()` is a function that transforms Arrays.  It **map**s one Array to another Array.  The most important part of its function signature is the callback.  The callback is called on each item in the Array and what that callback returns is what is put into the new Array returned by `map`.

It does not do anything special with what gets returned.  It does not call `.then()` on the items, it does not `await` anything.  It synchronously transforms data.

That means that if the callback returns a `Promise` (which all `async` functions do), all the promises will be "hot" and running in parallel.

In your example, if `getResult()` returns a `Promise` or is itself async, there isn't really a difference between your implementations.  `resultsPromises` will be populated by `Promise`s that may or may not be resolved yet.

If you want to wait for everything to finish before moving on, you need to use `Promise.all()`.

Additionally, if you only want 1 `getResults()` to be running at a time, use a regular `for` loop and `await` within the loop.

Answer (score 5):

If the intent of the first code snippet was to have a `.map` call that waits for all of the Promises to be resolved before returning (and to have those callbacks run sequentially) I'm afraid it doesn't work like that.   The `.map` function doesn't know how to do that with `async` functions.

This can be demonstrated with the following code:

```js
const array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
      
function getResult(n)
{
    console.log('starting ' + n);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('finished ' + n);
            resolve(n);
        }, 1000 * (Math.random(5) + 1));
    });
}

let promises = array.map(async (n) => {
    return await getResult(n);
});

console.log('map finished');

Promise.all(promises).then(console.log);
```

Where you'll see that the `.map` call finishes immediately before any of the asynchronous operations are completed.

Answer (score 1):

If `getResult` always returns a promise and never throws an error then both will behave the same.

Some promise returning functions can throw errors before the promise is returned, in this case wrapping the call to `getResult` in an async function will turn that thrown error into a rejected promise, which can be useful.

As has been stated in many comments, you never need `return await` - it is equivalent to adding `.then(result=>result)` on the end of a promise chain - it is (mostly) harmless but unessesary.  Just use `return`.