# js async await function execution order

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have `node.js` server. And I should store files on specific api.
My function for it:

```
exports.bootcampPhotoUpload = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  ...
  const fileNames = [];
  files.forEach((item) => {
    item.name = `photo_${bootcamp._id}${path.parse(item.name).ext}`;
    item.mv(`${process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${item.name}`, async err => {
      console.log(item.name); // logs on console second and shows fileName
      fileNames.push(item.name);
    });
  });

  console.log(fileNames); // logs on console firstly and shows []
  const updated = await Bootcamp.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { photo: fileNames });
  console.log(fileNames); // logs on console third and shows [filenames]
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: fileNames
  });
});
```

And on my model saved:

```
{
  photo: []
}
```

`item` object:

```
{ name: 'photo_2020-04-18 14.08.56.jpeg',
  data:
   <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 04 03 03 04 03 03 04 04 03 04 05 04 04 05 06 0a 07 06 06 06 06 0d 09 0a 08 ... >,
  size: 208920,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  md5: 'f8714b4e2135c3873c939a9464ea380a',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

For file upload I'm using `express-fileupload`. There is problem with `async/await` executing. **How can I save it correctly?**

Comment: You need to convert `item.mv` to a promise so you can `await` it then you must convert `file.forEach` to `for` to make the `await` work

Comment: @slebetman Can you give some example on answer pls. I don't understand :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map() function with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225272/map-function-with-async-await)

Comment: Forget that they're using map instead of forEach, the principle is the same.

Comment: Of what type is `item` in `file.forEach((item) => {`? Does the object hold by `item` have support for a Promises?

Comment: item is file object. `file.forEach` it array of files which I should store. Sorry for variable mistakes

Comment: What is `file object`? In the node API, there is no file object or anything in the file API that has an `mv` function, so it has to be from some module. Without knowing of what type `item` is not possible to know what API it supports, and without that information is it not possible to give a good answer.

Comment: @t.niese i written at now log of item object

Comment: A log of the object does not help, what module do you get that `item` object form, is there a link to the documentation API?

Comment: @t.niese I dont now for sure. I just it taken from `req.files`

Comment: Well, you should be sure about what you are using, how else do you want to be able to understand your code and solve problems if you have a bug? `(req, res, next) => {` indicates you are using `express.js`, but express js does not parse files that are sensed as part of a post request by default, so you registered a middleware that parses the request body, like `express-fileupload`, `multer`, `busboy`, … and that module defines the type of the `item` object.

Comment: @t.niese sorry. Im using `express-fileupload`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here.

1. Your `mv` function is async and callback-based, so you cannot use await directly.
2. Even if we turn it to promise-based, await won't work with forEach as we expect.

For the first one, we can use the normal for loop. And for the second one, we can use `util.promisify` to convert your `mv` function to promise based. Check [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) for doc on `util.promisify`.

Try the below code,

```
const util = require('util');

const fileNames = [];

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // 1. for loop here to support await in code block
    const item = files[i];
    item.name = `photo_${bootcamp._id}${path.parse(item.name).ext}`;
    try {
        await util.promisify(item.mv)(`${process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${item.name}`)   // 2. Promisify here so we can await
        console.log(item.name);
        fileNames.push(item.name);
    } catch (err) {
        // handle err
    }
}

console.log(fileNames);
```

Note: `util.promisify` could be slower, so it will be better if you find an alternate method/version of `mv` which already is promise-based.

Comment: It load's just one and then infinite loading

Comment: Is it printing the log `console.log(item.name);` for the first item?

Comment: If it is printing the `fileNames`, we could try adding console log in the catch block. Maybe some error is thrown

Comment: `Your mv function is async and callback-based, so you cannot use await directly.` there are many hybrid APIs, which return a Promise when no callback is provided. The `mv` function of `express-fileupload` belongs to this category, so there is no need to use `util.promisify` there.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the `mv` API used here. If it returns promise when passed single argument, then you are correct, we don't need to promisify it. We can do just `await item.mv(`${process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${item.name}`) `

Comment: @RaR there is no error. Just infinite loading and postman throws timeout

Comment: @aturan23, I guess we could find out the issue by adding more logs here. As you mentioned, it did print the fileName once, so there is no problem in resolving `mv` promise. But why it does not work for the second file? Do we know how many files are there in total? You could add logs before and after to see where exactly it is getting stuck, or use debugger

Comment: @aturan23, is it possible the second `mv` is taking a lot of time before that API is timing out?

Comment: @RaR I tried to log. And there loop is entry in try block prints `item.name` and stop there. Not going to throw or second iteration. Just stop in try block after `push` first item