# Map inside Mongo query returns empty variable outside the function, but not inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm attempting to build an array of objects using this map function with Mongo and node/express JS. For some reason the array returns empty when I console.log outside the map function, but inside the map function it shows the array being built with each iteration.

Why does this behaviour occur?

```
let allReviews = []

user.reviews.map( async (rev, index) => {
    const reviewer = await User.findOne({_id: rev.reviewerId},{password: 0})
        allReviews.push({
            avatar: reviewer.avatar,
            firstName: reviewer.firstName,
            lastName: reviewer.lastName,
            rating: rev.score,
            review: rev.review
        })
        // console.log(allReviews)
})
console.log(allReviews)
```

Comment: It is simply because database is slow, takes time but (outer) console.log doesn't. This will help you find an answer [map() function with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225272/map-function-with-async-await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous nature of javascript, you will need to wait for each of the database calls to come back before you can use the results.

In this case, `map` will return an array of Promises (because the callback is an `async` function) which need to be resolved before you can access the data in your `console.log`.

You can achieve this by doing `Promise.all`:

```
let allReviews = []

await Promise.all(user.reviews.map( async (rev, index) => {
    const reviewer = await User.findOne({_id: rev.reviewerId},{password: 0})
        allReviews.push({
            avatar: reviewer.avatar,
            firstName: reviewer.firstName,
            lastName: reviewer.lastName,
            rating: rev.score,
            review: rev.review
        })
}));
console.log(allReviews)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I have some reading up to do on Promises.

Comment: Glad it worked! It would be great if you could accept my answer