# I need to return a value from a asynchronous code, but I just get the Promise object in { pending } status

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

Please, I know this question has been answered before. I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val) & [this article](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8#.w234uo7h3), but I can't figure out how to fix my code yet.

I have created a `function` that reads some file's content & `returns` a `new Promise`. Here it's the `function`:

```
// array of string representing each file's path
const allSpecFiles = [
  '/path/to/the/file1.spec.js',
  '/path/to/the/file2.spec.js',
  '/path/to/the/file3.spec.js'
];

// method to read an individual file content & return a Promise
const readFileContent = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

Now, I'm trying to loop through an `array` of `strings` storing each file's `path`, call the `readFileContent()` method & pass current loop's value as its `param` with `map()` method since I would like to create another `array` of `strings` with each file's content.

This is what I have tried:

```
const allSpecFilesArr = allSpecFiles.map(async file => await readFileContent(file));
console.log(allSpecFilesArr); // I get Promise { <pending> }
```

I have also tried wrapping the whole `script` like so:

```
(async () => {
  const allSpecFilesArr = await allSpecFiles.map(file => readFileContent(file));
  console.log(allSpecFilesArr); // still prints Promise { <pending> }
})();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use Promise.all(allSpecFilesArr)

Comment: Gotta call `Promise.all(allSpecFilesArr).then(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to use `Promise.all(allSpecFilesArr)` because that is an array of promises. You can await it and you will receive an array of data returned from the inner resolved promises.

```
const fileContents = await Promise.all(allSpecFilesArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to wrap `fs.readFile`, use `fs/promises`. Try this out:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const paths = [ './one', './two' ]
;(async () => {
  const contents = await Promise.all(paths.map((p) => fs.readFile(p, 'utf8')))
  console.log(contents)
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is partially correct. You're `awaiting` the result of the map function which is, in this case, an array of promises.

If you removed await in front of the map call and called `await Promise.all(allSpecFilesArr)` you will get what you need.

You Could do something like this:

```
async read (paths) {
 const promises = [];
 for (path in paths) {
   promises.push(readFileContent(path));
 }

 
 const arrOfContentYouWant = await Promise.all(promises);
 return arrOfContentYouWant;
}
```

Comment: That's not correct, you can pass an async function to `map`, you just have to expect that you're going to get an array of Promises back. You can test this easily with something like `Promise.all([1,2,3].map(async (x) => x)).then(console.log)`. Also there is no `all` method on an array of promises, I think you meant `Promise.all`.

Comment: @ZacAnger, Thanks for pointing out the typo, I edited it.

For the map part, You're totally right, what I meant is without Promise.all we can not use async function with functions like map because synchronous code won't sit and wait for your asynchronous code to resolve, instead it will the fire the function and move on. I will remove this paragraph to avoid any confusion.

For more info about using map with promises https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225272/map-function-with-async-await