# Struggling to get my head around async, await and promises with mongoose

Tags: asynchronous, mongoose, async-await, promise

I have the following code that runs on a app.js server:

```
async function getNewNodesArray(level, nID, pdbID) {
    let newNodesArray = [];
    const dbNodes = await partsAssemblyModel.find({ParentID:pdbID}).exec();
    dbNodes.map(async(dbN) => {
        const dbChildren = partsAssemblyModel.find({ParentID:dbN.id}).exec();
        nID++;
        //newNode = {id:nID, dbId:dbN.id, name:dbN.Description, isParent:true}
        newNode = {id:nID, name:dbN.Description, isParent:(dbChildren.length > 0)}
        newNodesArray.push(newNode);
      })
    return newNodesArray;
}
```

The async function getNewNodesArray gets called from an express post function

```
app.post("/getTreeNodes", async (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    var ppp = await getNewNodesArray(pLevel, pId, pdbID);
    res.send(ppp);
});
```

I am trying to get all partsAssemblyModel documents which have  partsAssemblyModel documents linked to it with a `id-ParentID` relationship.
As is, the codes gets executed as expected except that the dbNodes object is the result of the query but the dbChildren is still a promise as is expected without the await.

If I add await to the dbChildren assignment, as follows:

```
const dbChildren = await partsAssemblyModel.find({ParentID:dbN.id}).exec();
```

the line gets executed the amount of times the map calls it, in succession and the the next line of execution is back in the app.post at `res.send(ppp)`;
Only after the app.post function completes execution does the execution return to nID++.

My question is, why doesn't the code continue execution on the next line after the line:

```
const dbChildren = await partsAssemblyModel.find({ParentID:dbN.id}).exec(); as it does in the line
const dbNodes = await partsAssemblyModel.find({ParentID:pdbID}).exec();
```

Any help to understand the reason is appreciated and a solution to the problem would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the children collection. You are only using its length, and for each child you are producing an object `newNode` that has the exact same properties for every child. I don't see how that is useful. Please clarify.

Comment: The map iterates over the dbNodes not the dbChildren. newNode is created for each dbNodes. The reason for querying the  dbChildren is only to find if dbNode has any children and then set isParent to true or false. I have changed the dbChildren query to findOne since I am not interested in any other data about the children

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map() function with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225272/map-function-with-async-await)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by replacing the map with a simple for statement:

```html
async function getNewNodesArray(level, nID, pdbID) {
  let newNodesArray = [];
  const myCount = await partsAssemblyModel.count();
  if (myCount === 0 ){return newNodesArray};
  const dbNodes = await partsAssemblyModel.find({ ParentID: pdbID }).exec();
  for ( var i = 0; i< dbNodes.length; i++){
    let dbChild = await partsAssemblyModel.findOne({ ParentID: dbNodes[i].id }).exec();
    console.log(typeof dbChildren);
    nID++;
    newNode = {id:nID, dbId:dbNodes[i].id, name:dbNodes[i].Description, isParent:(dbChild !== null)}
    //newNode = { id: nID, name: dbN.Description, isParent: (dbChildren.length > 0) }
    newNodesArray.push(newNode);
  }
  return newNodesArray;
}
```

But, I still don't understand why the map didn't work.