# Stripe calculate order amount function returns an error before async and await is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have created a calculate order amount function with async and await to get the item price(for each item)and then multiply it by the item amount and add the price to the variable price at the end...but the return (and a console log outside of the map) comes out before the map function.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_TEST_KEY);
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require("path");
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')
const productRoutes = require('./routes/product')
const orderRouts = require('./routes/order')
const Product = require('./models/productModel')
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
app.use('/product', productRoutes)
app.use('/user', userRoutes)
app.use('/orders', orderRouts)
const calculateAmount = async (items) => {
    const _id = items[0].id
    console.log(_id)
    const product = await Product.findById({ _id })
    const price = items[0].amount * product.price
    console.log(price)
    return price * 100;
};
const calculateOrderAmount = async (items) => {
    var price = 0
    await items.map(async (item) => {
        const _id = item.id;
        const product = await Product.findById({ _id });
        const fullPrice = item.amount * product.price
        console.log(`item total is ${fullPrice}`)
        price += fullPrice
        console.log(`inside the map is ${price}`)
    }
    );
    console.log(`outside the map is ${price}`)
    return price
};
app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;
    console.log(items)
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: items.length > 1 ? calculateOrderAmount(items) : calculateAmount(items),
        currency: "cad",
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true
        },
    });
    res.status(200).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
    })
})
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false)
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log('listeneing on port', process.env.PORT)
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

I tried to make a normal function and add async to it and await before the map but nothing changed...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map() function with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225272/map-function-with-async-await)

Answer (score 0):

try using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). this method that takes an iterable of promises and returns a `Promise`.

for example:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});

// output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

it waits until the promises resolve and then returns you a promise that you can use then() method to print or do whatever you want with your promise's output.

in your case it will be like this:

```
Promise.all([calculateAmount()]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
async function calculateAmount() {
    items.map(async (item) => {
      const _id = item.id;
      const product = await Product.findById(_id);
      const fullPrice = item.amount * product.price;
      console.log(`item total is ${fullPrice}`);
      price += fullPrice;
        console.log(`inside the map is ${price}`);
        return price 
    });
}
```

something like this

Comment: Still... Outside map exit first

Comment: can you reach me in Discord or any social media like Discord?
I need to see the new code you wrote

Comment: Shure, anything but Twitter